# Security Review - Untrusted users are allowed to input dangerous HTML tags

Tags: security

I am getting the following error in my security review:
Untrusted users are allowed to input dangerous HTML tags.

Is this because in my text formats I've got the following:
Plain text  All roles may use this format

Should I disable  anonymous users from being able to access plain text?

Also, it is saying:
It is recommended you remove the following tags from roles accessible by untrusted users.

```
img
```

Should I remove the img tag from authenticated users???? Does this mean that authenticated users will not be able to uploaded images to their site at all?

Comment: What security review tool are you using?

Comment: http://drupal.org/project/security_review @MPD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plain text is just that, no html tags, so this shouldn't be a security issue.

Perhaps the img tag is considered dangerous because it is possible to use a specially crafted png or jpg to launch an attack against a users browser.

Comment: Thanks for that @MarkMuhleder  . Any tips as to how to get rid of this error message "Untrusted users are allowed to input dangerous HTML tags."

Comment: Does the module let you specify some roles as "trusted users"?

Comment: I see that it does http://drupalcode.org/project/security_review.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-1.x:/README.txt "Navigate to
  39 Administer >> Reports >> Security Review >> Settings to mark which roles are
  40 untrusted."

Comment: Thank you!!!
Having only the anonymous user set as untrusted user fixed the problem.

Comment: It may "fix the problem" but is it the right thing to do? See http://drupalscout.com/knowledge-base/importance-user-roles-and-permissions-site-security

Answer (score -1):

img tags are [vulnerable to XSS attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet#Malformed_IMG_tags)

Since my site required roles higher than authenticated to submit content, I simply unchecked "authenticated user" from admin/config/content/formats/filtered_html and that solved my audit report.